# having to separate catking workspaces that do not interfere with each other

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have a simple problem. On my robot I have 2 catkin workspaces. Lets call them ws_A and ws_B. ws_A is used for execution of packages I have tested in ws_B. Now that means that I will end up having the same packages in ws_A as in ws_B sometimes. I was always under the impression that when I source the setup.bash of ws_A I am only going to access packages in ws_A even though there might be a package with the same name in ws_B. Through some try and error I found out that sometimes I am accessing packages from the wrong workspace. Is this normal? Is my assumption wrong and should I give packages in ws_A a different name than packages in ws_B?

Here is another thing that I find curious. When I do a catkin_find (although I have only sourced the setup.bash of ws_A) this is what I get:

```
/home/catkin_ws_A/devel/etc
/home/catkin_ws_A/devel/include
/home/catkin_ws_A/devel/lib
/home/catkin_ws_A/devel/share
/home/catkin_ws_B/devel/etc
/home/catkin_ws_B/devel/include
/home/catkin_ws_B/devel/lib
/home/catkin_ws_B/devel/share
/opt/ros/hydro/bin
/opt/ros/hydro/etc
/opt/ros/hydro/include
/opt/ros/hydro/lib
/opt/ros/hydro/share
```

Now I have also checked my bash.rc file but it is the correct workspace that I am sourcing

Any help would be appreciated

Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201384/having-to-separate-catking-workspaces-that-do-not-interfere-with-each-other/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2015-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever you build e.g. workspace B you must source your underlay workspace (/opt/ros/hydro) before.

If you have sourced workspace A that will result in chaining them.

To restart you probably want to remove the build / devel folder of both workspace and rebuild them with only the underlay being sourced.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2015-01-21**:
Hey Dirk,
as you said I deleted both /devel and /build, sourced the /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash and finally catkin_make my package. After a last sourcing of the setup.bash in devel/ everything works as expected

Thanks for the fast answer and good explanation

Marcus